# How Do I print a row of data based on the row name using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, yahoo-finance

I playing around with the yfinance API and I am at a stand still. Basically I am trying to print out only the row "Free cash flow" from the data below. Is there a way to do so? Meaning is there a way to print out the entire row for cash flow? Here is the problem. I tried printing out the row by iloc[24]. It works fine in this one case but if i were to switch the stock ticker to DAL. The row free cash flow becomes position 25.

```
     Breakdown      ttm 5/31/2019 5/31/2018 5/31/2017 5/31/2016
22  Capital Expenditure  -1060000  -1119000  -1028000  -1105000  -1143000
23  Operating Cash Flow  4996000  5903000   4955000   3640000   3096000 
24  Free Cash Flow  3936000  4784000   3927000   2535000   1953000
```

here is what my code looks like:

```
import pandas as pd
from yahoo_fin import stock_info as si


nikecashFlow = si.get_cash_flow("NKE")


pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)
print(nikecashFlow)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
nikecashFlow[nikecashFlow['Breakdown'] == 'Free Cash Flow']
```